# Internet Explorer: Strange behaviour of "Cache-Control: no-store, max-age=..."

Tags: internet-explorer, caching, cache-control

I'm currently facing some strange behaviour using the Internet Explorer (IE11 and all other "simulated versions" - IE8, IE9 and IE10 - in that IE11) when sending a `Cache-Control` header.

Our Web-Application is some kind of Web-Cam app showing live images using old school `HTML4` (requirement).
Those live images are sent using `Cache-Control: no-store, max-age=10`.
So that image should be cache for about 10 seconds **BUT NOT** stored on the disk. This is important since its filling up the hard drive otherwise! Our customers use some very old hardware with very (and I mean **very** limited resources)!

Then there are other kind of images which should be cached for some time longer, lets say an hour. So I send the same header with `Cache-Control: no-store, max-age=3600`.

**Problem**

The problem is now: The first type of images (with 10 seconds `max-age`) are cached correctly. But, the other images are not cached at all. The browser requests the image a second time when it should use the cached one.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further testing I come to the conclusion that this is some caching limitation of IE (tested with REAL 9, 10 and 11).

From the above mentioned *live image* there is only shown one at a time. So the IE only needs to cache **one** *instance* of that image (with that specific name, lets say `live_image.bmp`).

From the other images (need to be cached for an hour) there are shown several (up to 32) at a time with the *same image name* but different URLs (they are distinguished by a *time stamp* and some other parameter).

Obviously IE does only cache five of that images and refuses to cache any other one.